# Angular Universal getting the "No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'" error

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I just updated my Angular app from 5 to 7. In v. 5 I was able to do Server Side Rendering (SSR) just fine.

After the update, SSR fails with the following error (the build process works fine):

```
Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'.
at NgModuleResolver.resolve (/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:20015:27)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18657:47)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26060:55)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26041:40)
at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (/app/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26001:41)
at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (/app/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js:202:35)
at /app/node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine/bundles/express-engine.umd.js:109:25
at new ZoneAwarePromise (/app/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:910:29)
at getFactory (/app/node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine/bundles/express-engine.umd.js:95:12)
at View.engine (/app/node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine/bundles/express-engine.umd.js:74:13)
```

Given this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477712/error-no-ngmodule-metadata-found-for-object-object), I am not using `"bundleDependencies": "all"`, I've even tried to state explicitly `none` in `angular.json`, but it did not solve the issue.

I'm using this configuration in `angular.json`:

```
   "server": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/server",
        "main": "src/main.server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
        "bundleDependencies": "none"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "outputHashing": "none"
        }
      }
    }
```

I'm also lazy loading almost all modules, if that matters (it did not in v. 5):

```
{ path: 'private', loadChildren: '../private/private.module#PrivateModule', canActivate: [AuthGuardService], data: { state: 'private' } as RouteDataValues },
{
  path: '', component: PageWithFooterComponent, children: [
    { path: 'about', loadChildren: '../about/about.module#AboutModule', data: { state: 'about' } as RouteDataValues },
    { path: 'instructions', loadChildren: '../instructions/instructions.module#InstructionsModule', data: { state: 'instructions' } as RouteDataValues },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, data: { state: 'home' } as RouteDataValues },
    { path: 'home', redirectTo: '/' },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '/' }
  ]
}
```

My server:

```
import * as ngUniversal from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as compression from 'compression';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as path from 'path';
import * as appServer from '../dist/server/main.js';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-require-imports
require('zone.js/dist/zone-node');

const ROOT = path.resolve();

const app = express();

// Server-side rendering
function angularRouter(req, res): void {
  res.render('index', { req, res });
}

// Enable compression
app.use(compression());

// Root route before static files, or it will serve a static index.html, without pre-rendering
app.get('/', angularRouter);

// Serve the static files generated by the CLI (index.html, CSS? JS, assets...)
app.use(express.static('client'));

// Configure Angular Express engine
app.engine('html', ngUniversal.ngExpressEngine({ bootstrap: appServer.AppServerModuleNgFactory }));
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', path.join(ROOT, 'client'));

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

Any idea of what's not working?

Comment: Try importing `import 'reflect-metadata';` in server.ts before other imports

Comment: added it, unfortunately it did not solve the issue

Comment: Looks like you're using JitCompiler.

Comment: Try adding `core-js/es7/reflect';` in `polyfills.ts`

Comment: Maybe it's somehow connected with this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/28122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were multiple pieces missing, and it was indeed a problem with lazy loaded modules. To solve I've compared my server to [this one](https://github.com/ng-seed/universal).

Code added to my server:

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

...

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

...

const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('../dist/server/main.js');

...

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));
```